# Такое сокращение возможно?

Tags: аббревиатуры, условные-сокращения

Аналогичный период прошлого года (далее — АППГ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое сокращение вполне возможно — это [инициальная аббревиатура](https://publishing_dictionary.academic.ru/801/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0).

Такое сокращение называется **индивидуальным** — употребляется только в тексте одного издания, введенно его автором или издателем и так или иначе расшифровано в нем (в списке сокращений, внутри текста вслед за самим сокращением или перед ним, и в списке и внутри текста).

Например: ЗОИСП — заводской общественный институт совершенствования производства, СОИ — средства отображения информации.
Специальные инициальные аббревиатуры в литературе для специалистов не только желательны, но и необходимы, индивидуальные — желательны тем больше, чем чаще повторяется поддающееся сокращению словосочетание.

Подробнее здесь: [Аббревиатуры инициального типа](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0/).

Answer (score 1):

Конечно возможно. Такое сокращение называется [инициальной буквенной] аббревиатурой.